# react native how to get blink effect consistent

Tags: react-native, frame-rate

I need to have a consistent "blink" in very fast speeds, it works on slow speed

> ```
> timer speed > 100
> ```

but when using timer speed  < 50, I get some inconsistent blinking

https://youtu.be/qZAoTbVCW9E

so my question is, what is the maximum FPS blinking I could get? how to get the blinking consistent?

here my code for the basic blink

```
<View style={styles.container} backgroundColor = {this.state.torchStatus ? '#FF0000' : '#00FF00'}>
```

and the timer

```
  timer = () => {
let time = 100;

timer.setInterval(this, 'torch', 
() => this.setState({
  torchStatus:!this.state.torchStatus}, 
  ), 
  time);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native render at 60fps.
What you can try is setting your timer speed at 17 (1000 / 60 = 16.666 )